# How do you compute all combinations of lists within a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

As the questions states, I have a multi-dimensional list and I want to compute a list, with all possible combinations of those lists.
I only have a functions for one dimensional lists, which looks like this:

```
combinations :: [a] -> [[a]]
combinations xs = [ [x,y] | x <- xs, y <- xs]
```

Comment: Your solution allows *repetition*: you can generate `[2,2]` for a list `[1,2,3]`. Is this expected behavior, or a "bug"? If it is without repetition, it looks like you want to generate all possible permutations.

Comment: Yes, this behavior is wanted. The same appplies to the combinations of the lists within the list.

Comment: but then what is the output for `combinations [1,2,3]`? `[1,1,1]`, `[1,1,2]`, etc.? When do we stop with "picking" elements? It is simply not very clear to me what the expected output should be for `combinations [1,2,3]` for example.

Comment: The output for combinations [1,2,3] is: [[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]. But I can't use the same solution for multi-dimensional Lists. The desired output for multi-dimensional lists would look like this: combinationsM [[1,2],[3,4]] = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[1,2]]]

Comment: but then you already have what you are looking for, your `combinations` function will return `[1,1]`, `[1,2]`, etc. up to `[3,3]`.

Comment: If you use lists, like `[[1], [2,3]]` it will return as combinations `[[[1],[1]], [[1], [2,3]], [[2,3], [1]], [[2,3], [2,3]]]`

Comment: Why do `[[1,2],[1,2]]` and `[[3,4],[3,4]]` not appear in your desired output for `combinations [[1,2],[3,4]]`? If it was just a thinko, then why does your current implementation not meet this spec?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The desired output for multi-dimensional lists would look like this: `combinationsM [[1,2],[3,4]] = [[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[1,2]]]`

Your `combinations` function handles a list of lists of elements. It simply sees a list, and the items of these lists are lists, but the function does not care about this. For `[[1,2], [3,4]]` it will thus return:

```
ghci> combinations [[1,2], [3,4]]
[[[1,2],[1,2]],[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[1,2]],[[3,4],[3,4]]]
```

It thus has as combinations two times `[1,2]`, a `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`, a `[3,4]` and `[1,2]`, and two times `[3,4]`.

Your function thus already returns combinations of sublists. It simply works with lists of any type.

If you want to remove combinations where you pick the same sublist twice, you can define a helper that picks an element and also returns the list of the remaining elements:

```
pick :: [a] -> [(a, [a])]
pick [] = []
pick (x:xs) = (x, xs) : map … …
```

where the `…` parts are left as an exercise. The function should make a recursive call, and prepend all the lists with `x` in the `map … …` part.

This thus means that `pick [1,4,2,5]` returns `[(1, [4,2,5]), (2, [1,4,5]), (4, [1,2,5]), (5, [1,4,2])]`.

Then we can obtain the combinations without picking the same element twice with:

```
combinations :: [a] -> [[a]]
combinations xs = [[x, y] | (x, ys) <- pick xs, y <- ys]
```

It might also be better to return a list of 2-tuples, this adds more context to the return type, since then we know it is impossible that a combination contains a different number of items than 2:

```
combinations :: [a] -> [[a]]
combinations xs = [(x, y) | (x, ys) <- pick xs, y <- ys]
```